# My background is always only partially visible

Tags: image, background, lua, coronasdk

I'm really new, first time coding anything and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've tried this with multiple projects now following some tutorials and I keep getting the same result. Here's my code:

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local background = display.newImage("background.jpg")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try resizing the image with scale().

```
function stars:enterFrame( event )
    for i,v in ipairs( self ) do
            v:rotate(v.dr)
            if v.stageWidth < 1.5 * display.contentWidth then
                    v:scale(1.02, 1.02)
            else
                    v:scale(0.1, 0.1)
            end
    end
end
```

Here is the doc: http://developer.coronalabs.com/node/2452

Answer (score 1):

You are using `display.newImage` method. It will display an image with its actual resolution.
Try `display.newImageRect`, so that you can display an image in accordance with the screen size.

eg:

```
local background = display.newImageRect("background.jpg",display.contentWidth,display.contentHeight)
```

Also don't forget to position the image. This can also cause the same issue.

```
background.x = display.contentWidth/2
background.y = display.contentHeight/2
```

The two parameters after the image name are: `width` and `height` respectively.

For more details, refer:

- [display.newImageRect()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html)
- [display.newImage()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html)

Keep Coding........................ :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to respond to this kind of late.  This is a super easy solution. You need a bigger image since your image resolution is too small for the device.  If you want to scale the image up, just use this code:

```
background.x = display.contentWidth/2
background.y = display.contentHeight/2
background.xScale = 2
background.yScale = 2
```

Hope this helps.